# How to resume file upload to FTP in Midnight Commander?

Tags: linux, ftp, upload, midnight-commander

Trying to upload very big file and after some hours connection is lost. When I try to upload one more time, there is only Append option in Midnight Commander, which is not the same as Resume...

Answer (score 1):

You could use curl to continue interrupted file upload.

```
curl ftp://ftp_server_host:port/path_on_server/ -u username:userpassword -T filename_to_upload -C - -#
```

Comment: What does the only `-` do before `-#`?

Comment: @RahilWazir, if i'm remembering correctly, it preserve upload file name on server side. You could check it, with few simple experiments. Something like from tar examples over ssh, from this post: All your wishes come true: File transfer via SSH http://goo.gl/VjJ44C

Comment: I think `-C -` is connected with each other, removing either of these giving me `expected positive number parameter`

Comment: curl --help | less, return this info regarding: -C, --continue-at OFFSET  Resumed transfer offset. When you put "-C -", it check how much is uploaded on server, then resume upload, else, you could specify uploading from a custom OFFSET.